# Camel JUnit-Tests: wrong results with parallel execution

Tags: spring-boot, junit, apache-camel, parallel-testing

I use camel.version 2.18.1 and spring-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.
I have some more or less complex Camel routes, where messages from MQ Topics will be consumed, filtered, transformed and finally routed to different MQ Topics.

```
from("{{sourceEP}}").to("{{archiveEP}}")
   .process(new MyProcessor())
   .to("{{archiveEP}}").to("{{resultEP}}");
```

**application.properties**

```
sourceEP=jms:topic:SOURCE
archiveEP=jms:topic:ARCHIVE
resultEP=jms:topic:TARGET
```

For each route there exists more then 40 different scenarios. Therefore I have nearly 50 JUnit-Tests for each route, in total I have nearly 400 JUnit-Tests which I run with the maven-surefire-plugin to achieve parallel test execution.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <parallel>classes</parallel>
    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem is when the JUnit-Tests run in parallel, this will result in inconsistences in the producer endpoints (**EDIT:** for testing I use the Mock endpoints from Camel). The parallel tests affected the other tests and the expected number of messages in the target endpoints are incorrect.

**Test: application.properties**

```
sourceEP=direct:start
archiveEP=mock:archive
resultEP=mock:result
```

**RouteTest.java**

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class RouteTest {
    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "{{archiveEP}}")
    protected MockEndpoint archiveEndpoint;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "{{resultEP}}")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "{{sourceEP}}")
    protected ProducerTemplate sourceEndpoint;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sourceEndpoint.cleanUp();
        archiveEndpoint.reset();
        resultEndpoint.reset();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        sourceEndpoint.sendBody("some text");

        archiveEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(2);
        archiveEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("expected output");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        sourceEndpoint.sendBody("another text");

        archiveEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(2);
        archiveEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("another output");
    }

    ...
}
```

My question, is it possible at all to run the JUnit-Tests of Camel routes in parallel?

I tried to add `@DirtiesContext` on the test methods to force Spring Testing to automatically reload the CamelContext after each test method: http://camel.apache.org/testing.html
Which of course is not working at parallel test execution, because the result is still random and the expected number of messages is incorrect.

I ended up to set these tests which will test the Camel routes to `@NotThreadSafe` to enforce a single thread execution. Only these JUnit-Tests which will test other functionality than the Camel routing are executed in parallel.

But this is not a satisfied solution concerning the amount of nearly 400 JUnit-Tests.
Isn't there any configuration or setting to test Camel routes in parallel which will work correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your **MQ Topics are stateful** and therefore "not threadsafe". As soon as multiple tests run in parallel, the **number of messages in the topics is not foreseeable**.

To solve this problem you have to isolate the stateful part of your tests, i.e. your MQ Topics. You would have to generate unique MQ topic names per test, so that **each test has its own MQ topics**. If this is the case, the message size is well defined as in a single-thread execution.

Or as an in-topic-isolation alternative, you could use [JMS message selectors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html) to **isolate the messages in a topic** for the different tests. In this case each test must set a message header with a unique value and consumes only messages with this value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For testing I use the Mock endpoints from Camel which cause incorrect and random results. Maybe I will try to set an individual mock name for each test.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that. Yes, in that case you have to make sure that each test has its own MockEndpoint instances